# How to write a cover letter as proposing to apply for funding source with a professor

Tags: cv, application-cover-letter

I am going to finish soon my PhD. I want to apply for a postdoc fellowship. How can I contact a professor ? What is the common form of a cover letter in this situation ? Any advice, suggestion will be very appreciate.

Comment: Have you identified a funding source, and do you have a proposal in mind that you believe will be relevant to the professor (as well as appropriate for the funding)?

Comment: I identified a funding source.

Comment: If you want to maximise the chances of the professor responding positively then you probably want to send a letter which identifies a funding source and outlines the research you're proposing.